# asp.net mvc3, apit witter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-twitter

I have two asp.net mvc3 project on same machine

I used the same reference LinqToTwitter

in one project allows me to write: auth.CompleteAuthorization (Request.Url);

but the other shows me an error in auth.CompleteAuthorization (Request**.Url**);

request does not know the Url

Thanks

Comment: @Joe Mayo   any proposition for the probleme

Comment: the problem is that I used one in the controller and the other in a simple class

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because your `simple class` doesn't have a `Request` object with which to use and get the Url (or that `Request` object doesn't contain a method `Url`

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request` will also give you what you're looking for. You might want to also pass in the url via a parameter but it's hard to give anything more without more details.